# Erro Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string no codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

não estou conseguindo sair do lugar por causa desse erro.

Minha model está da seguinte forma

```
public function conf($dados){
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('senha',$dados);
    $query = $this->db->get('email');
    return $query->row();
}
```

e meu controller está da seguinte forma:

```
public function fim(){
    $this->load->model('quest_model');
    $this->load->helper('quest');
    $data = $this->input->post('senha');
    $dados['quest'] = $this->email_model->emailconf($data);
    $dados['quest1'] = $this->quest_model->get_quest(); 
    $dados['quest2'] = $this->quest_model->get_quest2(); 
    $dados['ques1'] = $this->quest_model->get_ques(); 
    $dados['ques2'] = $this->quest_model->get_ques2(); 
    $this->load->view('quest/file',$dados);
}
```

ja troquei o  $data por $data['p'] por exemplo e não parou de dar esse erro da mesma maneira.

o erro que está dando é o seguinte:
    A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: quest/file.php

Line Number: 49
```

eu usei o print_r e está printando tudo certinho, não estou conseguindo achar o erro, se puderem me ajudar agradeço muito

obrigado a todos

Comment: Sem saber o que tem nesse método `emaiconf()`, o que dá para sugerir é debugar criando um breakpoint. Na linha antes de `$dados['quest'] `, coloque assim: `var_dump($data);` e na linha seguinte coloque `var_dump($this->email_model->emailconf($data)); exit;`. Poste aí na pergunta o que retorna. Apenas tome cuidado com dados sensíveis, se tiver senha e coisas do tipo, substitua por dados fictícios antes de colocar aqui em público.

Comment: Coloque todo o código inclusive a View. O file.php também.

Comment: olá daniel, fiz o que você disse, o que retornou foi:

`string(9) "senhaX" object(stdClass)#20 (1) { ["idques"]=> string(1) "5" }`

Answer (score 1):

Não está claro onde é a tal linha 49 onde ocorre o erro, mas suponho que seja na `view`. A view deve estar fazendo algo como `echo $dados['quest'];` e, como `$dados['quest']` é um `stdClass`, é exibido essa mensagem de erro.

Portanto, acredito que basta fazer assim:

```
$dados['quest'] = $this->email_model->emailconf($data)->idques;
```

Remova o breakpoint e teste dessa forma que provavelmente sanará o problema.

Mas esteja ciente de que não posso garantir que o retorno será sempre um `stdClass` e nesse objeto terá sempre a propriedade `idques`. Nesse caso a consistência do retorno é responsabilidade sua em verificar.